# How can I create a PopUpMenu with dynamic data in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, popup

I want to show PopupMenu with dynamic data which will I got from API response. I tried with listview.builder inside PopupMenu child but it not works.

[image]

My code of showmenu()

```
void showMemberMenu() async {
    await showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(200, 150, 100, 100),
      items: [
        PopupMenuItem(
          value: 1,
          child: Text(
            "ROHIT",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                color: green3),
          ),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem(
          value: 2,
          child: Text(
            "REKHA",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                color: green3),
          ),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem(
          value: 3,
          child: Text(
            "DHRUV",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                color: green3),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      elevation: 8.0,
    ).then((value) {
      if (value != null) print(value);
    });
  }
```

Please help to get out from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `List.generate` method to generate the dynamic length of the list using the existing list you get from the API response.

Below is an example of how you can achieve it.

```dart
  void showMemberMenu() async {
    final List<String> popList = ['ROHIT', 'REKHA', 'DHRUV'];
    await showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(200, 150, 100, 100),
      items: List.generate(
        popList.length,
        (index) => PopupMenuItem(
          value: 1,
          child: Text(
            popList[index],
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      elevation: 8.0,
    ).then((value) {
      if (value != null) print(value);
    });
  }
```

> I've added `final List<String> popList = ['ROHIT', 'REKHA', 'DHRUV'];`
> just for the testing purpose, and you can replace it with your list
> you get from API response.

Comment: Could you please advise why List.generate is better here comparing to just using a .map om your list of strings?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

> call the api and put the value in PopupMenuItem

```
class PopupMenu {
 PopupMenu({@required this.title, @required this.onTap});

 final String title;
 final VoidCallback onTap;

 static PopupMenuButton<String> createPopup(List<PopupMenu> popupItems) {
 return PopupMenuButton<String>(
  onSelected: (value) {
    popupItems.firstWhere((e) => e.title == value).onTap();
  },
  itemBuilder: (context) => popupItems
      .map((item) => PopupMenuItem<String>(
            value: item.title,
            child: Text(
              item.title,
            ),
          ))
      .toList(),
    );
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to do something like this:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=a3f9002a37cbacc2cfae46174cbd2eba

you can add any state management to replace the FutureBuilder but this is the logical approach.

I hope it is helpful.